# Do all operator overloads put the operator after objects whose overload would be called?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have got a question about unary operator overloading. The code is as follows:

```
class Fraction { 
 public: 
   Fraction() {} 
   Fraction(int a); 
   Fraction(int n, int d, int reduce=1); 
   Fraction operator +(const Fraction& y) const; 
   Fraction operator -(const Fraction& y) const;
   Fraction operator -() const;            // unary negation 

  // etc.
};
```

for unary operator`-`, the code is as follows:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator -() const {   return (Fraction(-num, denom, 0)); }
```

Suppse we have three `Fraction` objects, `f1`,`f2` and `f3`.
I know for code:

`f3=f1+f2` is equal to `f3=f1.operator+(f2)`, that is the object in front of the operator will call the operator and the one behind will be passed as parameter, right?

Then, for unary operator `-`, the code is

`f3=-f1`

following the thought above for operator `+`, I think the code should be like `f3=f1-`, which is equal to `f3=f1.operator-()`. Why the actual code is `f3=-f1` instead of `f3=f1-`? I think the object in front of the operator should call it... I know in math, it is `f3=-f1`, but how can the compiler recognize the code `f3=-f1` which actually is that `f1` calls the operator? how does it know that in this case, `-` is an unary operator?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Because the language (and math) just is that way.

Comment: @deviantfan, then how can the compiler recognize that?

Comment: The compiler sees a `-` with only a right-hand side operand, so it knows to use the unary version.

Comment: Stop believing that the following sentence is true: "I think the object in front of the operator should call it... ". Because it´s not. The C++ standard does not say that every usage of op overloading should have the object in front.

Comment: @Adam, how clever it is!! ;)

Comment: @deviantfan so it is just a rule of thumb, right? at least, I think, for binary operator, this rule is true, right?

Comment: @Jessica.Jin: Yes, for binary ops it´s true in C++.

Comment: I generally prefer to declare mathematical operators as `friend`s.  This makes it a little more clear, in my opinion.  Eg `friend Fraction operator-(const Fraction& f1, const Fraction& f2)` and `friend Fraction operator-(const Fraction& f)`.

Comment: @5gon12eder I think it is less clear to use friends, as they violate encapsulation and it's a bunch of extra typing which clutters up the class definition.  (I prefer non-member non-friend)

Comment: @MattMcNabb If non-member non-friend is possible, then it should certainly be used.  But often enough, it is not and then `friend`s don't break encapsulation any more than members do.  Yes, you'll effectively need to type out the additional parameter that would otherwise have been the `this` pointer but that's what I think makes it more clear.  Might be partially due to my Python experience.

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking".  Because you say "here comes my question" and then say "I think the code should be like f3=f1-".  Stating what you think--which is contrary to observable behavior and the language specification--isn't actually a question.  If you'd like to edit your post to something like *"Do all operator overloads in C++ place the operator after the object whose overloaded method would be called?  Are there counterexamples?"* then the answer is no and counterexamples can be given.

Comment: @HostileFork, thanks for your advice! I have made a change.

Comment: re. the new title, *none* of the unary operators do, except for postfix-++

Comment: You have to remember that built-in operators (from C) came first, and operator overloading was added later *to support those operators also for user-defined types*. I.e., `-42` came first (where there is no object to act upon, no member functions etc.) and `-my_object` came later, supporting the *same, well known syntax* for class objects.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two unary operators in which the reference to the object comes first.  That's postfix `++` and postfix `--`.

The syntax for how to distinguish these in your overloads is a little bit odd.  You add a fake argument:

```
class Ptr_to_X {
    // ...
    X operator++();      //prefix: no argument
    X& operator++(int);  //postfix: because of
                         //the argument

    X operator--();      //prefix: no argument
    X& operator--(int);  //postfix: because of
                         //the argument
};
```

[Here's some history of how that came to be.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c++.moderated/hybKn7omx_w/T5x0YFR2oG0J)  Make of it what you will.

Other than the postfix forms of those, all the other unary operators appear before the object reference.  That covers:

- Unary minus (-)
- Unary plus (+)
- Ones complement (~)
- Address of (&)
- Pointer dereference (*)
- Logical NOT (! or not)

If it makes you uncomfortable because you are used to seeing "the method" always appearing "after the object"...that's too bad.  Some languages have syntax which is regimented and regular...using all prefix or all postfix notation, for instance.  But cognitive scientists and linguists believe there are arguments that the human mind operates on a kind of [language instinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-bar_theory), and I'd argue that many of the purely consistent languages battle against our mind's desire to create the structure "in our heads".

Either way, as @dyp says, all these operators came from C (except the ability to write `!` as `not`, which I do, because it's in the standard and is harder to miss).  It would be weird if you negated integers with a minus sign in front...and then negated a complex number class with the minus sign in back.